# FAST search: Search crawled succesfully, but I still do not see new search results, I think index issue

Tags: crawling, fast-search, index

I am using SP 2010 and FAST search. I have 2 FAST search servers and 2 front end servers and 2 app servers. I do every 4 hours an automatic incremental crawl. I do not have an automatic full crawl scheduled. This was working always fine. When I search now on keywords I do not find results from new listitems or documents. Only from old documents.

when I go to the crawl log I see it crawled successfully my new documents. But I still cannot find them! Is this maybe an index issue? I do not want to reset the whole index because we are using thousands of documents and have shousands end users. Please help?

Comment: Run indexeradmin -a status and see if you have any items in the not_indexed xml atrribute returned. If it's different than zero, try a indexeradmin -a resumeindexing, if indexing somehow has been suspended.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a permission issue. Can you log in with the default content access account and try whether you see results or not?

Comment: I logged in with site administrator account. No results.